# Accessing parent node in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, mootools

Having problems calling my parent Title ("Main title") in my JSON object. Below is a fiddle with what I currently have. (I can get it to call all child nodes in items, but again need to figure out how to call "title: Main Title")

http://jsfiddle.net/VVAFM/3/

Current JSON Tree

```
{
    "title": "Main Title",
    "items": [{
        "title": "Sub Title 1 "
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub Title 2",
        "items": [{
            "title": "Sub Item 1"
        },
        {
            "title": "Sub Item 2"
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub Title 3",
        "items": [{
            "title": "Sub Item 1"
        },
        {
            "title": "Sub Item 2"
        }]
    },
    {
        "title": "Sub Title 4 "
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the new JSON SELECT engine, looks interesting and affords CSS-like select statements over your JSON.

http://jsonselect.org/#overview

having said that, you can reference it differently like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/VVAFM/4/

the title var will refer to main title, always.

good luck :)

Comment: So in that same context, if I were to call the title "Sub Item" would it be items.items.items.title?

Comment: well, it will/can be recursive, won't it. you can pass it the whole json bean or a part of it, but each grouping that you do pass will have 2 properties: `title: "string", items: []`.